# Using Scanner to read a file with spaces

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a txt file with * and spaces using Scanner. So far, I have written the following code for the input:

```
**   S       ***

while(lineNum <= height){
            //System.out.println("Maze created");
            lineTokenizer = new Scanner(s.nextLine());

            for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
                for(int j=0;j<width;j++){
                    if (lineTokenizer.hasNext()) {
                        lineTokenizer.useDelimiter("\\s+");
                    maze[i][j]=lineTokenizer.next();
                }
            }
            }
            lineNum++;
            }
```

However, I am still unable to proceed beyond the

> **

point. Can you please tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

I've edited the Q to include the loop . lineNum will keep track of the no of lines (I am starting from line 2 of the file ) and store every character read in a 2d Array.

Comment: you'll need to post more code than that, what does "proceed beyond" mean. where is your loop

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @75inchpianist- I've edited the Q. Proceed beyond, in the sense, I couldn't read beyond the space in the file.

Comment: your j is always 0 for every iteration. is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the code in the Q.

Comment: @75inchpianist- I am trying to store the *,S and space in the 2D array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have multiple white spaces, your delimiter should be `\\s+`

```
  lineTokenizer.useDelimiter("\\s+");
```